# A question on zero divisors

Tags: integral-domain

In the ring $\mathbb Z_n$, the divisors of zero are precisely those elements $m\in \mathbb Z_n$ such that $(m,n) > 1$.

Proof:

Let $d = (m,n)$ and note that
                                                                                             $$m\cdot \frac nd = \frac md \cdot n \equiv 0 \ \ \ \ (\text{mod } n).$$

If $d > 1$, then $0 \not\equiv n/d \pmod n$ so that $m$ is a zero divisor. Conversely, if $d = 1$ and $ma \equiv 0\ (\text{mod }p)$, then $n|ma$ so that necessarily $n|a$. This implies $a ≡ 0 \ (\text{mod }p)$ so that $m$ is not a zero divisor.

Please help explain the proof in a more lucid language.

Comment: thanks for editing exactly the way I wanted to post..

Comment: It would help if you specified what in particular you might like elucidated, as I'm not sure I can explain the general idea much better than the proof already did.

Comment: @jgon thanks for responding.. actually I'm not able to decipher well the proof wants to convey.

Comment: It may help to explain what you do understand.  Do you know what it means to be a zero divisor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've got a $p$ sneaking in where you want $n$.

Then there are two parts to the argument based on whether $d = \gcd(m,n)$ is $1$ or more than $1$.

If $d > 1$, then you get a zero divisor because the product of $m$ and $n/d$ is $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (and both $m$, $n/d < n$).

If $d = 1$, then let's look at a possible equation in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ showing that a number $m$ is a zero divisor, namely $$m a = 0 \pmod{n},$$ where neither $m$ nor $a$ are congruent to $0$ mod $n$.

Then $ma$ is a multiple of $n$ so $n \mid ma$ and because $n$ and $m$ are coprime, $n$ must actually divide $a$. But to be a zero divisor there must be an equation where neither $m$, $a$ are already $0$ mod $n$.

The proof is ok, apart from the erroneous $p$, but just a stream-of-consciousness proof that is not very well structured.